# Error POSTing data with Qt

Tags: qt, post

I want to POST data to a PHP form using this code, but after compiling I have message:

> Object::connect: No such signal NetworkReplyImpl::finished(QNetworkReply*):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QUrl params;
    QUrl url("localhost/test2.php");
    params.addQueryItem("name","aaa");
    params.addQueryItem("country","bbb");

    QByteArray data;
    data.append(params.toString());
    data.remove(0,1);

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(QNetworkRequest(url), data);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QString data = reply->readAll().trimmed();
    qDebug() << data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message says it quite clear: `QNetworkReply` doesn't have a signal `finished(QNetworkReply*)`. It does however have a signal [`finished()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#finished), which takes no arguments. You can't pass the reply this way.